# TabBar App stopped rotating since I used a rootviewcontroller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar app that has always allowed for rotation.  I had to add a login screen for the app and in order to prevent the app from showing the tabbar first on start-up i added the login screen as the app's rootviewcontroller.  This allows me to use the login view as a singleton as well.

Since this change my app no longer rotates.  How can i get the message to the tabbar controller to rotate in order for the app to work as previously.

i tried changing the shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation method to say YES but the status bar moves and not the tab bar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation: method in your new root view controller is being called. I suspect that the rotation message is being sent to the root view controller rather than the current view controller you are on. Handle rotation from there. I had this problem with the camera picker.